# AJAX file progress not working / addEventListener('progress') does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

The event progress listener does not seem to be firing in AJAX (using Chrome web browser). The file uploads as expected when just using the form submit function to the form action. The file is uploading behind the scenes when using AJAX, the progress is not being displayed by the console.

UPDATE: This appears to be working in safari but not Chrome...  (locally)

UPDATE: Still working fine in Safari, but also not in 'Webview' on Android React-Native.. which I assume uses Chrome technology?

Javascript:

```
 document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

        if(document.querySelector('#customFile').files.length == 0) {
            alert('Error : No file selected');
            return;
        }
    
        // first file that was chosen
        var file = document.querySelector('#customFile').files[0];
    
        // allowed types
        var mime_types = [ 'application/pdf'];
        
        // validate MIME type
        if(mime_types.indexOf(file.type) == -1) {
            alert('Error : Incorrect file type');
            return;
        }
        // upload file now
        var data = new FormData();
    
    // file selected by the user
    // in case of multiple files append each of them
    data.append('file', document.querySelector('#customFile').files[0]);
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('post', '/upload/save_file', true); 
    
    // upload progress event
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    
        var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total)*100;
        
        // Percentage of upload completed
        console.log(percent_complete);
    });
    
    // AJAX request finished event
    request.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        // HTTP status message
        console.log(request.status);
    
        // request.response will hold the response from the server
        console.log(request.response);
    });
    
    // send POST request to server side script
    request.send(data);
    });
```

Comment: Did you check your antivirus program? See [XMLHttpRequest upload progress not firing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21417842/215552)

Comment: I'm on a mac.. I do not have antivirus.  Chrome does have adblock.. I'll try pausing it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lay in the Service Worker which was also listening for fetch requests.

A detailed description of the problem can be found here:

https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1141

Specifically adding this at the top of the Fetch Event Handler:

```
 if (event.request.method === 'POST') {
  return;
}
```